# Capture Order Cancellation from Admin via Observer

Tags: event-observer

**Magento ver. 1.9.1.0**

I have a working module that observes **checkout_submit_all_after**, this logs the order, however I need to remove log entries when the order is 
a) refunded
b) Cancelled in the admin

To monitor the change I am using **sales_order_save_after**, this is called when the order is placed but not when any actions are taken from the admin. i.e. I receive log entries when there is a new order but at not when I cancel an order

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

**app/etc/modules/Module_Followuporderemail.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Followuporderemail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Module_Followuporderemail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Module/Followuporderemail/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Followuporderemail>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Module_Followuporderemail>
    </modules>
  <global>
      <models>
        <followuporderemail>
            <class>Module_Followuporderemail_Model</class>
        </followuporderemail>
    </models>
    <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <followuporderemail>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followuporderemail/observer</class>
                    <method>logOrder</method>
                </followuporderemail>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <watchorderstatus>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followuporderemail/observer</class>
                    <method>checkCancelled</method>
                </watchorderstatus>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events> 
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Module/Followiporderemail/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Module_Followuporderemail_Model_Observer
{
    public function logOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        Mage::log('New Order Placed: ' . $order_id);
    }

    public function checkCancelled( $observer)
    {
        Mage::log('Order Status Change: ');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of checkout_submit_all_after is  one time when order has been placed.

But `sales_order_save_after` called serveral times,when any save event(`save()`) are happened on `Sales/order` model `(Mage::getModel('sales/order'))`.

For your requirement, You should remove `sales_order_save_after` from *global area*  and   put it under  adminhtml

```
 <adminhtml> <!-- remove from global  area -->
        <sales_order_save_after>
    ......
    </sales_order_save_after>
    </events> 
  </adminhtml>
```

Also add this code at observer for check   status changes

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            //order not saved in the database
            return $this;
        }

        /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

        $OldData=$order->getOrigData();
        $NewData=$order->getData();
        $OldState==$order->getOrigData('state');
        $NewState=$order->getState();
        $OldStatus=$order->getOrigData('status');
        $NewStatus=$order->getStatus();


        /* Fire  when New Status  and  old Statu are not same 
     when New status is  canceled
    */
        if(($OldStatus!=$NewStatus) && ($NewStatus == 'canceled'){

        }



        return $this;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this event

> order_cancel_after